# v-on:click не правильно срабатывает

Tags: vue.js

Может кто-нибудь подсказать почему @click срабатывает ни в тот момент когда кликнул по кнопке, а после того когда кликнул и убрал курсор с объекта?

[image: код]

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего в компоненте v-btn эвент тоже как то обрабатывается. Посмотри что там происходит кнопка работает с Экшеном.
Возможно туда надо подавать функцию для нажатия как то по другому.